# Pentaho SQL (Native) connection error

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, pentaho

I'm running a couple of SQL connections from a Job. They are all working with the **sqljdbc4.jar**, but when I run them with MS SQL Server *Native* (which was by default) instead of MS SQL Server  - they fail with this error:

```
Error connecting to database [xxx_zxxxx] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.


    org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
    Error occured while trying to connect to the database

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:427)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:361)
    .................
    Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
```

Can this be caused by the new JDK_1.8 I've installed? How to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably have both sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar on the classpath and sqljdbc.jar gets loaded first, or you are using an **old** version of the driver (before Java 7 existed).

Comment: Try using sqljdbc41.jar !! As per this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422(v=sql.110).aspx there seems to be some compatiblity issues with sqljdbc4 !!!

Comment: @Rishu any idea where to find this *4.1* version, since I only [found 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around solution that worked just fine in my case. Just remove the  **sqljdbc.jar** and leave only **sqljdbc4.jar** in my file system. Also added only sqljdbc4.jar to the System variables > path